# Perls Of Wisdom For a .Net Programmer

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I like to think that recently I have moved from complete beginner to beginner. It has been a hard road and one on which I took many wrong turns. Very rarely in any profession is there a place where so many rock stars gather, this is something I would like to take advantage of.

What I would like to ask is what are your perls of wisdom for a .net programmer. They can be anything you feel of value, a concept, a book, a process that should be followed, anything of that nature, it doesn't have to be .net specific just contextual.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and respond.

Comment: Scratch that, apparently asking the wisdom of your "elders" is not allowed but jokes and cartoons are?

Comment: Joke questions are not allowed on SO either. Some still exist for historical reasons, but they should probably be moved somewhere else like Meta, thereby avoiding these kinds of arguments altogether.

Comment: I agree, thanks for letting me know about the historical nature, I'm sure it has come up more than once but this is the first time I have seen a reason for their existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing I tell everybody:

This is a knowledge field. If you stop learning, your skills will become quickly out-dated.

No matter how good you think you are, don't stop learning.

Comment: Thanks, this is something that is very easy to forget since it is so "simple" and an intrinsic part of programming.

Comment: That's a genuine thanks, on re Reading it sounds sarcastic, it's not meant to be :)